# how to create animation with 5 images using story board in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

i need to create animation with images more than two images.i'm done the animation with two images as shown below. i'm beginner to this environment please help me to create the story board with five images.

```
  in class i'm calling this method.


  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard1.Begin();  
    }





      <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
       <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"  Storyboard.TargetName="image2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>

        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>





    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="230"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">

            <Image  Stretch="Uniform" Name="image1" Source="/Images/w1.png" />
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Name="image2" Source="/Images/w2.png" />
          <!--  
            <Image  Stretch="Uniform" Name="image3" Source="/Images/w3.png" />
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Name="image4" Source="/Images/w4.png" />
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Name="image4" Source="/Images/w5.png" />
           -->

        </Grid>
    </Grid>



     Please Help me.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you just want to switch images? Kinda like a flipbook yeah?

If that is the case animating the `Opacity` is bad way to do it.  Why not just animate the `Source` and switch it from w1.png to w2.png to w3.png etc?

That way you can simplified your code to basically

```XAML
<Image  Stretch="Uniform" Name="myImage" Source="/Images/w1.png" />
```

And your `StoryBoard` to

```XAML
<Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)"  Storyboard.TargetName="myImage" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="="/Images/w1.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="="/Images/w2.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="="/Images/w3.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="="/Images/w4.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="="/Images/w5.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

---

If you want to keep some weird Opacity animation, you can also add them into the `StoryBoard` as well.

Comment: @madhubabu np :), please mark the question as solved.  good luck on your wp8 app :D